# Mac Mini Streaming to HDTV

Tags: display, mac-mini, displayport, hdmi, television

I am considering purchasing a Mac Mini in a few weeks and am just wondering about the best way to wire it to a 1920x1080p Monitor as well as a 720p HDTV. I would like to put streaming video on the television (Like the Stanley Cup Playoff) which is via my web browser, I would also like to be able to surf the net on the monitor while the game is streaming on the tube.

I am totally new to Mac, I have never even had an iPod so I am unsure what limitations may or may not exist.

Any assistance would be wonderful

Rob

EDIT: I do own an Apple TV. If I got a Mac Mini would it replace the Apple TV? I want to be able to surf netflix and my iTunes on the television but I would also like to be able to work on the computer on the monitor at the same time, I don't know if this will do that though.

Answer (score 2):

The Mac mini has an HDMI port and a thunderbolt port. You can hook your TV up via the HDMI port and your monitor via the thunderbolt port, although if you are planning on using a non-apple monitor you will most likely need an adapter. Essentially you'll have a dual monitor computer. Move a browser window with the game on to the TV. You can run another browser session or some other app in the second monitor.